# How to execute a example in pcl tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how to execute an example in pcl tutorial( http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials ). This question is same as this page ( http://answers.ros.org/question/48583/pcl_tutorial-how-to-show-the-point-cloud/ ), but the result was't shown on the page. Could anyone tell me how to execute it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153936/how-to-execute-a-example-in-pcl-tutorial/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-16**:
This isn´t really a question asked to the community, but a question that gets answered immediately (?) It makes more sense to post an answer to the question you link above or edit the corresponding wiki page you link above with the additional info you provide.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-17**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher: Thank you for your comments. Your comments is correct. If I answer your question, I gets an answer immediately and nobody check  an article in 2012. Because some people post their question without checking same question. By the way, I may edit the corresponding wiki page?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-17**:
Yes, after logging in you're free to edit the wiki page. Also, if someone finds the question from 2012
through search, you posting an answer to another place doesn't really help.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-17**:
Your comment is also right! I'll try to edit the wiki page. Thanks, @Stefan Kohlbrecher!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-04-17**:
Speaking of raising an attention upon editing wiki, what I also like to do in order to get reviewed is to edit wiki, get a link for the diff (from `info` page on the particular wiki page), and post on issue tracker of the corresponding repository.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-17**:
Thanks, @IsaacSaito!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understood it ,so I will describe here for anyone who have a trouble.
In order to execute a example_voxelgrid.cpp, I had to input three command on three terminals. As an additional information, I use a kinect.

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/camera/depth/points
rosrun rviz rviz
```

The Input on the second sentence means a topic that is shown with `rostopic list`.
On Rviz, you have to change some parameters.

```
Fixed Frame: map -> camera_link
PointCloud2/Topic: /output
```

This output on above means 37 line in example_voxelgrid.cpp.
The results of executing the preceding statement are shown below.

[image: image description]

This picture shows an environment in front of a kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0